# Notion of a basis that allows infinite sums

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, fourier-analysis, schauder-basis

So with no other structure it is clear that a vector space has no notion of convergence and thus infinite sums make no sense. However, suppose $V$ is an inner product space, then we have a norm which induces a topology on $V$ so we can talk about convergence. Is there then a notion of a basis which allows infinite sums?

My question is mainly motivated by statements I see by physicists in introductory quantum mechanics textbooks. For example, I have seen physicist claim that the vector space of solutions to the time independent Schroedinger equation confined to an infinite square well of width $a$ has a countable basis given by:
$$\psi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{a}x\right)$$
and that every solution can be written as an infinite sum of these functions for certain constants $c_n\in \mathbb{R}$. So is this just abuse of language or is there actually a way of defining a basis that allows for such infinite sums?

Moreover, I have seen physicists talk about an uncountably infinite basis of functions parameterized by $\mathbb{R}$ where any solution to some PDE can be written as an integral over this basis for some choice of square integrable function $f$. Generally this is talked about in the context of Fourier transformations, which I am not crazy familiar with outside of what was covered in my undergraduate real analysis course. Does it also make sense to call this a basis in this context or is it again abuse of language?

Edit: I see in the tags that my first question is yes, and that it is called a Schauder Basis. So my main question is can we extend this notion to an uncountable basis when it makes sense to talk of integration.

Comment: It gets worse: the members of a physicist's uncountable "basis" are usually not in the vector space at all, because they are not square integrable functions.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Well that is certainly cause for concern. Do you think you could provide an answer in more detail?

Comment: The rigorous approach to these matters is using the Spectral Theorem.  See e.g. Reed and Simon, Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics I: Functional Analysis, and II: Fourier Analysis, Self-Adjointness.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ok I will look into these. Thank you for the sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hilbert spaces we have available the notion of an [orthonormal or Hilbert basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis), which is not a basis in the usual algebraic sense (sometimes called a [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis#Related_concepts) in this context to distinguish it) but allows infinite sums which converge with respect to the norm. The $\psi_n$ are an orthonormal basis in this sense. These figure prominently in the [spectral theorem for compact operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator_on_Hilbert_space#Spectral_theorem). This is not an abuse of language, just a generalization of the meaning of "basis" suitable to this context.

The uncountable stuff is formalized mathematically by the concept of a [direct integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_integral). I think most mathematicians would consider the use of the word "basis" here an abuse of language but maybe physicists don't, I don't know. This sort of thing is needed for the spectral theorem for non-compact operators.